# Is a charred resistor open or short?

Tags: resistors, short-circuit

I've a problem where I should expect how a circuit will behave with a charred resistor. So should I consider this resistor a connecting wire or an open switch?

Comment: You should consider both situations, or rather prevent it from happening. There is no way of telling what will happen to a component unless you have very specific types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When resistors overheat, a variety of things can happen, some of which will increase resistance and some of which will decrease resistance--typically by creating alternate current paths.  Overheated resistors are not particularly likely to ever represent a "dead short", but high-value resistors may have their resistance drop by multiple orders of magnitude.  Note that subjecting a resistor to sustained moderate overloading may yield very different behavior from subjecting it to severe overvoltage conditions.  If an overvoltage condition causes an arc within a resistor's insulating material, the resistance may be greatly reduced as long as the arc is sustained, and the susceptibility to arcing may be permanently reduced, even if the resistance under low-voltage conditions is relatively unaffected.

Comment: Like if wire-wound resistors melt, then perhaps the winding thereby shortens. It may help to refer to this diagram: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Types_of_winding_by_Zureks.png

Comment: A normal resistor used within its specified operating conditions will pass an amount of current proportional to the voltage applied across it.  Resistors that fail in certain ways, especially by arcing over, may pass amounts of current which vary differently with regard to applied voltage.  If a device passes 1mA per volt while the applied voltage is below 100V, but once that occurs will act much like a 10-ohm resistor in parallel with a 100V clamp, until current falls below 10mA in which case it will resume earlier behavior, what is its "resistance"?

Comment: PS--I think I've seen resistors which used a zig-zagged wire rather than a spiral.  Is there a term for that?  Also, looking at the pictures, I wonder if there are any wire-wound resistors which include a "safety winding" along with the main winding, such that any condition which would result in reduction in resistance would also short to the safety winding--a condition which could trigger an equipment shutdown?